# Seven Matches Digits

Tags: matches, seven-segment

[image]

a) Remove some of the match sticks from the above 2 x 2 x 1 surface grid to reveal the figures below.
[image]

Rotation, flipping, segment sharing are allowed.[image]

b) Place some match sticks on the above 1 x 1 x 2 grid to create the figures below.[image]

Rotation, flipping, segment sharing are allowed.  Congruent digits as one and bending are also allowed.

How can these be done?

Comment: There are 12 different possible places in a. Do we just leave some blank?

Comment: Yes ,some blank segments

Comment: in the first question, figure 1 doesn't have blank segments?

Comment: @Jamal Senjaya-Yes,since figure 1 is surrounded by spaces, its blank segments can be not within the grid

Comment: Are we supposed to imagine that this is an opaque object, or would match sticks not directly on the face we look at also be visible through? i.e. the opposite face and any edge face sticks

Comment: @IanMacDonald, The segments(sticks) of digits and its  blank segment are coplanar in (a) also in (b) but can be bent at the mid segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer to part (a)*

Just like [my answer here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/111799/75318), I converted this problem into a SAT instance.

> The code (for this part and the next) is [in the same place](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/224bae32a3dca7ab0c85ade5a045a923). There is no solution with the 7 as given in this part, but there are solutions with the 7 as given in the *second* part (four segments on). Even then, none of these solutions have a distinct 2 and 5. The best you can do is show the 2 and all other digits (except 5, of course) unflipped, for which there is essentially a unique solution:
> [image]
> The dashed edge is optional.

*Answer to part (b)*

> The solution is also unique up to rotations and reflections. Making as many digits unflipped as possible:
> [image]

Answer (score 4):

I think I have found the answer for the first question

> [image: solution]

Comment: Where's "1" in this answer?

Comment: @G0BLiN : Figure 1 doesn't have blank segment, so just assume 7 also contains 1.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya-ok with type of 7 and 1 is not a problem  but note that a) dont allow congruent as one (only in b)) ,so we should show  2 , 5, 6 ,9 .