# Fitting 7 Segments Digits on Smallest Rectangular Grid

Tags: seven-segment

[image: grid]

On the 2 x 1 grid all 7- segment digits above can be formed one at a time as seen on clocks, calculators and other digital devices.
If we are allowed to flip or rotate and overlap segments, how should these digits be configured inside the 3 x 4 grid, so we can see all of them at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's my solution, with the following features:

1. Distinct 2 and 5
2. Distinct 6 and 9
3. Rotations only (Mirror images of numbers don't look all that nice)
4. No upside-down digits (max. rotation 90 degrees)

> [image]

This was **way** more difficult than expected. There may be other non-mirror solutions apart from this one and its symmetries, but if there are, they are few and far between.

Comment: Nice animations!

Comment: there the no flipped digit solution!

Comment: @JS1 Thanks! I made a new version now that I had time; all done with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)'s copy-paste, rectangle select, and a paintbucket full of 36% transparent black paint :-)

Answer (score 3):

> [image]

Explanation:

> 0: middle row, first two columns
>  1: top row, first two columns
>  2 and 5: top two rows, third column
>  3: bottom two rows, second column
>  4: top row, last two columns
>  6 and 9: bottom two rows, third column
>  7: bottom row, first two columns
>  8: bottom row, last two columns
>  Note the last column of the middle row isn't even used.

Comment: full overlapping of 2 & 5 or 6 & 9 conceals the digits beneath thus we cant see

Answer (score 2):

After finding and writing up the solution to [this slightly related problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111795/number-box-puzzle) I decided to impose similar constraints for this problem, formulate it as a SAT instance and solve:

- No flipping
- The digits can only lie in one of *two orthogonal* orientations; this implies that 6 and 9 cannot be represented by the same segments

> The on/off states of the grid segments are the 31 *base variables*. For each combination of digit and possible location for a digit (there are 17 with my self-imposed constraints) a *position variable* representing whether that digit appears at that position is introduced, along with the eight clauses needed to enforce it. Finally ten clauses are introduced, one for each digit, representing the need for at least one corresponding position variable to be true. The code I wrote to generate the DIMACS file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/224bae32a3dca7ab0c85ade5a045a923).

The end result of this was

> no solution for the width-4 height-3 case and **exactly one solution** for the width-3 height-4 case: [image]

---

*Edit:*

> With no holds barred (flipping, 2/5 and 6/9 occupying the same space allowed) and a **3×3** grid there is also a unique solution:
> [image]

Comment: Note that my 308 solution also has only the 4,9,7,1 horizontal.

Comment: @TSLF But your 9 and your 7 point in opposite directions there. See my edit, which shows an even tighter solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Solution for 4 x 3 grid

5   -4 6

3  0  8

2  - 9

-7 -  1

Comment: The “no upside-downies” bit was just me trying to show off; my upvote is for the brilliant alternative “no-mirrored-digits” solution to the original question you had before you rotated it 90 degrees :-)

Comment: Oh, oops, it’s the OP’s self-answer. Sorry :-)